# Should Solr be used as read-only database?

Tags: mysql, solr

I am going to build a website. It's kind of a magazine that allows users all over the globe to access. The data might grow extremely large. I am using mySQL database as core database to perform read/write operations such as add new users, add new article, and so on.
Since the data in the core database might be extremely large, I'm thinking using Apache Solr as a read-only database (I'm using Solr as a search engine anyway) to read data each time a user view an article, user profile, and so on.

Is that a good approach in pratice? what are pros and cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Solr for a Full Text Search engine as well as the Read Only datastore as the reads can be very fast especially if you are using Filer Query to query Solr.
The Con can be the delay in data as you would be replicating the data from MySql to Solr, there would be a delay for records to show up in Solr.